# Building MST from a graph with "very few" edges in linear time

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I was at an interview and interviewer asked me a question:

We have a graph G(V,E), we can find MST using prim's or kruskal algorithm. But these algorithms do not take into the account that there are "very few" edges in G. How can we use this information to improve time complexity of finding MST? Can we find MST in linear time?

The only thing I could remember was that Kruskal's algorithm is faster in a sparse graphs while Prim's algorithm is faster in really dense graphs. But I couldn't answer him how to use prior knowledge about the number of edges to make MST in linear time.

Any insight or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any explicit meaning for "very few"? Maybe `|E| = O(|V|)`? Maybe `|E| = |V| + O(1)`?

Comment: No actually. I asked but he didn't say anything.

Comment: this problem is the subject of CLRS problem 23-2 "Minimum spanning tree on sparse graph"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kruskal's algorithm is pretty much linear after sorting the edges. If you use a union find structure like [disjoint set forest](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/16/Small16.pdf) The complexity for processing a single edge will be in the order of lg*(n) where n is the number of vertices and this function grows so slowly that for this case can be considered constant. However the problem is that to sort the edges you still need a `O(m * log(m))`. Where `m` is the number of edges.

Prim's algorithm will not be able to take advantage of the fact that the edges are very few.

One approach that you can use is something like a 'reversed' MST approach where you start off with all edges and remove the **longest** edge until the graph becomes disconnected. You keep doing that until only `n - 1` edges are left. Still note that this will be better than Kruskal only if the number of edges to remove `k` are few enough so that `k * n < m * log(m)`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah that makes sense perfectly.

Comment: Can you throw some light on how to use Disjoint Set data structure to know whether graph is connected or not, after removing an edge.

Comment: @premktiw I don't think you can use Disjoint Set for this, at least I can not think of an approach from the top of my head. Still we don't need constant complexity for the check in this case. My assumption is that we do a linear check to find the longest edge so we can also do a linear check for connectivity

Answer (score 0):

Lets say |E| = |V| +c ,c being a small constant. You can run DFS on the graph and every time you detect a circle, remove the largest edge. you must do that c +1 times. O(c+1 * |E|) = O(E) linear time in theory.